# Android database can't update

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I'll try update database but it can't update. It insert correctly but don't change rows with new ones.

```
    mydatabase = getMydatabase();// this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues devices = new ContentValues();
    devices.put(KEY_NAME, name);
    devices.put(KEY_ADDRESS, address);
    devices.put(KEY_GRADE, grade);
    devices.put(KEY_ARRAY,gradeArray);
    try{
    mydatabase.insertOrThrow(DATABASE_TABLE, null, devices);
    } catch (SQLiteConstraintException e) {
        String where = "'"+address+"'='"+KEY_ADDRESS+"'";
        mydatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, devices, where,null);
    }
    mydatabase.close();
```

This code in function which take different grade and gradeArray values. They are strings.

Database create statement:

```
String create = String.format("CREATE TABLE %s ( %s INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,"+
                            " %s TEXT ,%s TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE , %s TEXT NOT NULL,  %s TEXT);",
                    DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROW_ID, KEY_NAME, KEY_ADDRESS, KEY_GRADE, KEY_ARRAY);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String where = "'"+address+"'='"+KEY_ADDRESS+"'";
```

You're comparing a literal to a literal here. Remove the `''` from the column name, e.g.

```
String where = KEY_ADDRESS + "='"+address+"'";
```

To avoid SQL injection as such, use parameters:

```
String where = KEY_ADDRESS + "=?";
mydatabase.update(DATABASE_TABLE, devices, where, new String[] { address });
```

Comment: Thanks. String where = "address=?"; is also worked for me. I got 4 minus so i guess this question will be closed soon. Maybe i'll delete this.